# I am scraping discord and The function below gives me message: 404 ,code: 404 in json file. I cant understand why. It is my own server

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp, discord

It is my own server and I am trying to retrieve messages, overall my goal is to make a discord scraper.

On a side note,Bots require server permissions and so I am working on web scraping, although I guess you need to be a part of the server to scrape it too I guess. If anyone has a better idea to scrape servers that they aren't a part of please let me know. This is for an NLP project.

```
    def retrieve_messages(channelid):
    num=0
    headers = {
        'authorization': 'MTAzMjczMTk2MTc0OTQyNjE4Ng.GWupVp.8-6vbgdumzJkF7sQNR9Xv-scMALYEGWQtKsmA0'
    }
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels{channelid}',headers=headers
        )
    
    jsonn=json.loads(r.text)
    return jsonn
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `/` between `/channels{channelid}`. Try like this

```
r = requests.get(
    f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}',headers=headers
    )
```